# Scanning NFC type v tag

Tags: java, android, nfc

I am developing an application in Android studio that should be to scan for an NFC type v tag. If I can just instantiate the tag object then I can perform further operations with the tag but I am having trouble with scanning the tag.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NfcTool"
        tools:targetApi="30">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and here is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.nfctool;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.NfcV;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Enable NFC foreground dispatch to capture NFC intents

        // creates an explicit intent to launch the MainActivity when an NFC intent is dispatched.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        // This flag ensures that if the MainActivity is already in the foreground, it will not be recreated and instead receive the NFC intent in its onNewIntent() method.
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        // creates a pending intent that wraps the intent we created earlier. It will be used to handle the NFC intent when it arrives.
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        // enables the foreground dispatch system for NFC intents
        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, null, null);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Disable NFC foreground dispatch
        nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        Log.d("DEBUG","###############" + intent.getAction());

        // Check if the intent has an NFC tag
//        if(intent.getAction() == NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED){
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())){

            // Get the tag object
            Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

            // Check if the tag supports NfcV technology
            if (NfcV.get(tag) != null) {

                // Instantiate the NfcV object with the tag
                NfcV nfcvTag = NfcV.get(tag);

                // Use the NfcV object for further operations
                // ...


                Toast.makeText(this, "NFC tag detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Unsupported tag technology", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when I log the value of intent.getAction() in the onNewIntent method it logs a null value
`D  ###############null`

So I know that the action of the intent is not being set. IF someone could point out where I am going wrong or what I am missing it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible problem the `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE` should be `PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE`

This is because a `PendingIntent` is an object can be handed to other applications so that they can perform the action you described on your behalf at a later time.

So you are handing this to the System NFC service which then adds the NFC data and returns it to at a later time, Thus it has to be changeable (Mutable).

Also from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc#foreground-dispatch) You can see in the example it has to be Mutable.

Also note that using `enableForegroundDispatch` is actually not the best way to use NFC using `enableReaderMode` is a newer and much better API to use NFC. `enableReaderMode` does not use Intent's and gives you more control, it is easy to do NFC operations in a background Thread (which is recommended), for writing to NFC Tag's it is much more reliable and leads to less errors.