# NFC tag intent is always null ( android )

Tags: android, kotlin, nfc

I'm trying to read an NFC. The intent is being called and the logs are showing up as well. However, the intent always comes up null. I am using NFC 213, and I've also added the tech list and everything. I have added the manifest etc.

I've found some solutions, but they are very outdated and no longer work or have some deprecated implementation.

Here's the code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var nfcAdapter: NfcAdapter? = null
    private var pendingIntent: PendingIntent? = null
    private var intentFiltersArray: Array<IntentFilter>? = null

    private lateinit var textView: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView)

        setupNFC()
    }

    private fun setupNFC() {
        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this)
        if (nfcAdapter == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "NFC not available on this device")
            return
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "NFC adapter initialized")
        }

        if (nfcAdapter != null) {
            if (nfcAdapter!!.isEnabled) {
                // NFC is enabled
                Log.d(TAG, "NFC is enabled.")
            } else {
                // NFC is supported but not enabled
                Log.d(TAG, "NFC is supported but not enabled.")
            }
        }

        val intent = Intent(this, javaClass).apply {
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
        }

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

        // Intent filter for all three types of NFC intent
        val ndefIntentFilter = IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED).apply {
            try {
                addDataType("*/*")
            } catch (e: IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException) {
                throw RuntimeException("Failed to add data type", e)
            }
        }

        intentFiltersArray = arrayOf(ndefIntentFilter, IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED), IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED))

        Log.d(TAG, "NFC setup complete")
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        // Enable foreground dispatch
        nfcAdapter?.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, intentFiltersArray, null)
        Log.d(TAG, "Foreground dispatch enabled")
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()

        // Disable foreground dispatch
        nfcAdapter?.disableForegroundDispatch(this)
        Log.d(TAG, "Foreground dispatch disabled")
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        Log.d(TAG,"On new intent called")
        textView.text = "NFC"
        val tag: Tag? = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)
        if (tag != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "TAG IS NOT NULL");
            val techList = tag.techList
            techList.forEach { tech -> Log.d(TAG, "Tech: $tech") }
        }



    }


}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanning NFC type v tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76430211/scanning-nfc-type-v-tag)