# NFC: Tap & pay with NFC tags not working on Android

Tags: android, nfc, tap-payment

Tap & Pay functionality with NFC Tags stopped working after migrating Android version from 11 to 12.

With following code, on tapping the NFC tag in NFC enabled area the device is vibrating but nothing is happening after that.
Previously this functionality was working end to end when target SDK was 30 i.e. for Android version 11.
Sharing my code below, please help me finding what is missed in the code and what can be the possible solution, thanks!

**NFCBaseActivity**

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED == intent.action) {
            val rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES)
            if (rawMsgs != null) {
                onTagTapped(NfcUtil.getSuperTagId(intent), NfcUtil.getSuperTagData(rawMsgs))
            } else{
                onTagTapped(NfcUtil.getSuperTagId(intent), null)
            }
        }
    }
```

calling below method from **onResume()**

```
protected fun enableNfcForegroundDispatch(environment: String) {
        try {
            val intentFiltersArray = NfcUtil.getIntentFilters(environment)
            val intent = Intent(this, javaClass).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
            val nfcPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
            adapter?.enableForegroundDispatch(this, nfcPendingIntent, intentFiltersArray, null)
        } catch (ex: IllegalStateException) {
            Timber.e(ex, "Error enabling NFC foreground dispatch")
        }
    }
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
    <!--Need this feature to use NFC functionality -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />

    <!-- Need this permission to read nfc tags in foreground-->
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.NFC"
        android:required="false" />
    .
    .
    .
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Can you share all the manifest codes?

Comment: Are you using `enableForegroundDispatch` ? as there was a change to `PendingIntent` in Android 12, sharing your `enableForegroundDispatch` code would help if you are using it.

Comment: @Andrew yes I'm using enableForegroundDispatch in onResume(), I've added it now in my question. Please have a look and let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanning NFC type v tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76430211/scanning-nfc-type-v-tag)

Comment: `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE` should be `PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE` as the NFC service needs to be able change the Pending intent to add the NFC Tag data. When it is returned to `onNewIntent` `intent.action` is null because the Intent could not be changed. See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#DeclareMutabilityPendingIntent for more details

Comment: @Andrew Worked like a charm, thanks a ton! and please post this an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE` should be `PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE` as the NFC service needs to be able change the Pending intent to add the NFC Tag data.

When it is returned to `onNewIntent` `intent.action` is null because the Intent could not be changed. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#DeclareMutabilityPendingIntent) for more detail